# If $y=f(x)$ is a function derivative implicitly for the locus $y^3+2xy^2+x=4$, how I find $f(1)$??

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> Question: Suppose that $y = f(x)$ is a derivative function given implicitly from the equation $y^3+2xy^2+x=4$. Suppose that, also,  $1\in Df$
>
> a) Compute $f(1)$.
>
> b) Determine the equation of the tangent line to $f$ in $x=1$.

I don't know How to find $f(1)$. I know that $F(x,y)= 0$ defines implicitly a function derivative $y= f(x)$. But when I differentiate I have this:

\begin{gather}
\frac{d}{dx}[y^3+2xy^2+x] = \frac{d}{dx}[4]
\\
3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}+2y^2+4xy\frac{dy}{dx}+1 =0
\\
3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}+4xy\frac{dy}{dx} =-1-2y^2
\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1-2y^2}{3y^2+4xy}
\end{gather}

Where do I deduce $f(1)$ from?

Because I need to determine the equation of the line, but I can't without this result.

Comment: What do you need derivatives for?  If $y=f(x)$ and $y^3 + 2xy^2 + x=4$ then just plug in: $y^3 + 2y^2 - 3 = 0$. Where a solution for $y$ is a solution of $f(1)$.  Youre going to have three possible answers. You dont have any other information to work with.

Comment: you have a typo in your answer. $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1-2y^2}{3y^2+4xy}$

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum $y=f(x)$ is the derivative, which is confusing, that is to say $f(x) = \frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: @ChristopherMarley How would you know? Youre not the questioner.  It explicitly says at the beginning that $y =f(x)$.  Im just reading whats being said.

Comment: I'm reading in between the lines. @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Sometimes the foreign speakers can't communicate well enough. Look at the last sentence of the explanation: He needs the derivative for the equation of the (tangent) line.

Comment: Okay, he needs a derivative. Thats fine. It doesnt mean $y'=f(x)$, as that blatantly contradicts the statement that $y=f(x)$.  Reading "in between the lines" is not what a mathematician does.  There is no room for poetry or artistic license here.  Ambiguity in a question makes the question impossible to answer so I will wait until the questioner can string together a cogent question. I wont be making assumptions on meaning.  If you want to waste your time answering what you think might be the question, and risk misleading the questioner, go ahead. I think it unethical, however.

Comment: My question asks for :
a) calculate f(1):
b) Determine the equation of the line in graphic of the f in point x = 1

Sorry, If my question was confused.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum "You are going to have three possible answers". One is $y=1$. The two remaining ones, please?

Comment: I dont know, @user, I didnt care to take my time solving a cubic. Solutions could be trivial, could not be.  If you know $y=1$ then you can factor out to a quadratic.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum I just flagged your last comment as "rude or abusive".

Comment: I only don't have understood what the question wants, Now that I begin study derivative implicitly, sorry for my English I'm learning too

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum I reported you to the moderator. In the meanwhile, you can read [Be nice](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: I left “derivative function”, but it probably is “explicit function”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find $f(1)$ from the original equation because it means finding the $y$-value when $x=1$.

$$y^3+2xy^2+x=4$$

Substitute in $x=1$ and you get

$$\begin{split}
0 &= y^3+2y^2-3\\
&=(y-1)(y^2+3y+3)
\end{split}$$

Note that $\sqrt{3^2-4(3)}$ is complex so $y=1$ is the only choice.

Comment: Thank you a lot!